# How to listen to the remote controller sticks values updates using DJI SDK?

Tags: objective-c, swift, sdk, frameworks, dji-sdk

I need help in triggering an action when a change in the sticks of the remote controller of the drone is held. Actually, I want to stop the timeline mission of the drone automatically when a user starts playing with the sticks.

I think I need to keep listening to the sticks values using DJIStick class as a reference from the documentation but I could not handle that correctly!

https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/Stick/DJIStick.html?Phclickrefb=1011lcQs3Ept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved listening to the change in the sticks using the following logic:

1. Set the delegate for the ViewController class
2. Define a new function that returns and fetches the DJIRemoteController instance of the connected device (drone)

> ```
> class ViewController: DJIRemoteControllerDelegate {
>
> func fetchRemoteController() -> DJIRemoteController? {
>         if !(DJISDKManager.product() != nil){
>             return nil
>         }
>         if DJISDKManager.product() is DJIAircraft {
>             return (DJISDKManager.product() as! DJIAircraft).remoteController
>         }
>         return nil
>     }
> }
> ```

3. Then, you need to call the previous function when after the drone state is flying (in my case after the drone started the timeline mission)

> let remote = self.fetchRemoteController()
>
> remote?.delegate = self

4. Now, the following function should be triggered automatically when a change occurs the sticks

   ```
   func remoteController(_ rc: DJIRemoteController, didUpdate state: 
   DJIRCHardwareState) {

        if state.rightStick.verticalPosition > 0 || state.rightStick.verticalPosition < 0 || state.rightStick.horizontalPosition > 0 || state.rightStick.horizontalPosition < 0 || state.leftStick.verticalPosition > 0 || state.leftStick.verticalPosition < 0 || state.leftStick.horizontalPosition > 0 || state.leftStick.horizontalPosition < 0 {
                print("Detected move in Sticks while mission is started so stop the mission")
                print("Right Stick vertical position is \(state.rightStick.verticalPosition) and horizontal position \(state.rightStick.horizontalPosition)")
                print("Left Stick Value is \(state.leftStick.verticalPosition) and horizontal position \(state.leftStick.horizontalPosition)")
        }

    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To get up to date information on the state of the remote controller's joysticks you could hook into the `setHardwareStateCallback` of the `RemoteController` class which `updates the Remote Controller's current hardware state (e.g. the state of the physical buttons and joysticks)` according to the [documentation](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/RemoteController/DJIRemoteController_DJIRCHardwareState.html).

This would allow you to respond to the position of the joysticks very frequently.

However you are going to have to store the previous values over a period of time and create some logic to determine if the user has been changing the values of the sticks consistently over that period.

An easier option may be to just give the user the option to stop the mission in your UI. Also another emergency option to stop a mission (if that is your use case) using the remote is to switch flight mode on the remote - this would automatically stop the mission.